# Check if host computer is online with PHP?

Tags: php, function, internet-connection

I've been having some issues with my Internet connection and I was wondering what is the fastest, error-less and most reliable way to check if the host computer is connected to the Internet.

I'm looking for something like `is_online()` that returns true when online and false when not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've benchmarked some solutions: [file_get_contents](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) with HEAD request, [gethostbynamel](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php), [checkdnsrr](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php) and the following solution seems to be more than 100 faster than all the others:

```
function is_online()
{
    return (checkdnsrr('google.com', 'ANY') && checkdnsrr('yahoo.com', 'ANY') && checkdnsrr('microsoft.com', 'ANY'));
}
```

Takes about one microsecond per each host, while `file_get_contents` for instance takes more than one second per each host (when offline).

Comment: Warning, only available in PHP 5.3.0.

Comment: @Wiliam: On Windows... Who uses that in production anyway?

Comment: Developers that works in Windows with <5.3 php versions for example. It's only a warning for them :)

Comment: This is a great answer, too bad it hadn't come up in my searches over the years :( Anyway, got it now! +1

Comment: This is faster because it's not actually checking if the host is online, it's just checking DNS. To check if a host is online, you need to talk to it via file_get_contents or it's underlying fopen or via sockets or however you chose, but it's an expensive, in terms of time, to do the check.

Answer (score 2):

You could send a ping to a host that is probably up (e.g. Google).

There seems to be no PHP built-in for this, so you'd have to resort to shell commands. The return value of `ping` on *nix can tell you whether a reply was received.

**Update**: `ping -c1 -q -w1` should be the right command on Linux. This will give you exit code 0 if a reply was received, something else otherwise, and it times out after one second.

Hence, something like this (warning, my PHP is rusty) should do the trick:

```
function is_online() {
    $retval = 0;
    system("ping -c1 -q -w1", $retval);
    return $retval == 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, thanks. I probably won't use this but for the reference here is an article that shows how to implement ping natively on PHP: http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?lngWId=8&txtCodeId=1786 and also a PEAR package that does all this: http://pear.php.net/package/Net_Ping

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do a number of `HTTP GET` (or better still `HTTP HEAD` for speed) requests on popular web sites? Use *majority voting* to decide on the answer.

You can *sometimes* rely on `ping` too (through a system call in PHP) but note that not all web sites respond to ICMP (ping) requests.

**Note** that by increasing the number of ping/http requests you make before drawing a conclusion helps with the *confidence level* of the answer but *can't* be error free in the worst of cases.

Comment: Thanks I was thinking in the same lines as you, do you happen to know how to make HEAD requests with file_get_contents() and stream_context_create()? I'm asking this because I don't wanna rely just on CURL to make the request.

Comment: $context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('method' => 'HEAD'))); $response = file_get_contents($url, null, $context); $response will be false (===) on failure. The returned headers will be stored in $http_response_header.

Comment: I've benchmarked it and quering google.com takes more than 1 second per request, check my answer for a follow up.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget this assumes that your server will respond to ICMP requests. If that's the case then I agree, Net_Ping is probably the way to go. Failing that you could use the Net_Socket package, also on PEAR, to attempt a connection to some port that you know will get a response from - perhaps port 7 or port 80 depending on what services you have running.